# Projecting 3D Position Vector / Point onto a Line That Doesn't Go Through Origin

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors, 3d

I have position vector $\vec{P}$ with component $\langle0,2,1\rangle$, and line $l$ with equation $\langle2t,2t,2\rangle$ where $\vec{V}$ is the direction vector $\langle2,2,0\rangle$. My question is how to project $\vec{P}$ onto $l$ ? If $l$ doesn't go through $(0,0,2)$ and it goes through origin i could've easily project $\vec{P}$ onto $l$ by projecting it onto $\vec{V}$. Can i just go ahead and project $\vec{P}$ onto $\vec{V}$ then translate it 2 unit up and call that projection of $\vec{P}$ onto $l$ ?

Comment: Close. First translate so that the line does pass through the origin, perform the projection, then translate back.

Comment: Well that's what i said in my question. Translating L so it pass through origin means that it will be the just same as it's direction vector V (but when t = 1 L becomes V itself), and then translate back by 2 unit up. Is that any different ?

Comment: I think you meant to said translate L and P 2 unit down and then do projection of P' onto V and then translate back 2 unit up, right ?

Comment: Of course. You have to translate _everything_.